# REGEXP_SUBSTR get second match

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I have this **String :**

```
"Y::_~XXXXXX XXXXXX~MIGRATION~_~_~_~_~0~JOD50.000~USD257.43::JOD"
```

I wanted to get the list of currencies via **`Regex`**.

So far, I can only get the first match using this query:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('Y::_~XXXXXX XXXXXX~MIGRATION~_~_~_~_~0~JOD50.000~USD257.43::JOD','[a-zA-z]{3}$') 
from dual;
```

Can you please help me get the second match which is USD?? Thanks. :D

By the way, I am planning to use the **`Regex`** dynamically.

So given any output of String, I wanted to get 3-length **String :**  either by occurence

```
"Y::_~XXXXXX XXXXXX~MIGRATION~_~_~_~_~0~JOD50.000~USD257.43::JOD"
```

> JOD
>
> USD

Comment: Getting the second match for your regex doesn't make much sense - your regex contains a `$` anchor which matches only at the end of the string. Did you mean to use `USD` instead?

Comment: Yes! How can i get USD instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second occurrence of your pattern, you should set the `occurrence` parameter of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to 2:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Dummy text 123USD another dummy text 456USD', 
  '[0-9]{3}USD',
  1,
  2) from dual
```

**UPDATE**

To get all groups of 3 letters that are surrounded by non-letters, you can use this query:

```
select match, substr(match, 2, 3) from (
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('Y::_~XXXXXX XXXXXX~MIGRATION~_~_~_~_~0~JOD50.000~USD257.43::JOD',
  '(^|[^a-zA-Z])[a-zA-z]{3}([^a-zA-Z]|$)',
  1,
  level) as match
from dual
connect by level <= 100
) where match is not null
```

This 
 - matches all groups of 3 letters [a-zA-Z]{3}
 - that either occur at the start of the string `^` or have a non-letter character in front `[^a-zA-Z]
 - and either occur at the end of the string`$`or have a non-letter character afterwards`[^a-zA-Z]
 - uses `CONNECT BY` to generate the first 100 numbers using the `LEVEL` pseudocolumn
 - feeds the level as occurrence parameter into `REGEXP_SUBSTR`
 - excludes all invalid matches with `WHERE MATCH IS NOT NULL`
 - extracts the relevant part of the match with `SUBSTR`

(you could also use negative lookahead / lookbehind to ensure you have groups of exactly 3 letters, of course)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. But I'd like my regex to be dynamic? Can you come up with a regex without the hard-coded String to search??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't exactly get what you want. You want all groups of letters of length 3 that are surrounded by non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: Yes.. Either you can get the first match/second match by occurence

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted (by clicking the check button).